# InterlockedExchange() and thread safety

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

```
volatile LONG g_lRunning = 1;

bool IsRunningEx()
{
   return ::InterlockedExchange(&g_lRunning, 1) == 1;
}

bool IsRunning()
{
   return g_lRunning == 1;
}

void Close()
{
   ::InterlockedExchange(&g_lRunning, FALSE);
}

void f1()
{
   while (IsRunning())
   {
      // do some thing
   }
}

void f2()
{
   Close();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   std::thread t1(f1);
   std::thread t2(f2);
   t1.detach();
   t2.detach();

   return 0;
}

void f1_()
{
   while (IsRunningEx())
   {
     // do some thing
   }

   ::InterlockedExchange(&g_lRunning, FALSE); 
   // I must do some thing like this in here or in IsRunningEx internal, 
   // because after calling IsRunningEx() g_lRunning will be TRUE. 
   // So when call IsRunningEx() next time, it will return TURE, 
   // but it would return FALSE in hope.
}
```

1. Is it thread safety, reading `g_lRunning` direct in `IsRunning()` and writing `g_lRunning` using `InterlockedExchange` in `Close()` above code ?
2. if I replace `f1` with `f1_`, I will have a problem just as comment in `f1_`, do you have any better idea（Don't use atom in c++11）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding question 1:
As far as I understand it, it is safe to read g_lRunning directly. Writes have to be made atomic, so for every write operation there is an `InterlockedXXX` function, but reads don't need to be atomic and there is no `InterlockedXXX` function for just reading.

When talking about thread safety you need to keep in mind that volatile does not guarantee acquire/release semantics, but in your case this should not be a problem.

Regarding question 2:
You could also use `return ::InterlockedCompareExchange(&g_lRunning, 0, 0) == 1`. You could replace the two zeroes by any value you like.

If you can use C++11 I'd really recommend to use the new `std::atomic`.

Comment: The documentation for InterlockedCompareExchange says "This function is atomic *with respect to calls to other interlocked functions*." (emphasis mine).  So I believe that in general you do need to both write and read via interlocked functions.  However, if you know that you're running on x86 or amd64, it should be OK because reading a 32-bit value is inherently atomic on those platforms.  (I'm not sure about ARM.)

Comment: Yes it's wrong (although msvc has flags to give volatiles acquire/release semantics which does make it ok), the problem isn't atomicity (pretty much everybody guarantees that for aligned word integer reads/writes) but visibility guarantees.. x86 indeed gives those so it's ok, but e.g. ARM, IA64, alpha,.. don't

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your creating - in effect - a SimpleSpinLock, so it would be worth bearing in mind that whilst you are running in the while loop you are spinning and wasting CPU cycles.  A kernel mode lock may be more effective here if you are intending to spin for a long time.

Comment: That's not a spin lock, that's a "do something until I tell you to stop" construct.

Comment: Yeah I think I jumped the gun a bit there. I'll leave it there to higlight my mistake, downvote me if you wish. It'll teach me to read  questions properly in the future.